# Is there any name/occurence to this sequence of numbers?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, dg.differential-geometry, terminology

I am curious if there is any name for this sequence of numbers, or any occasion that this sequence is used.

The sequence is $(c_1,c_2,c_3,\cdots)$ with recursive formula
$$c_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_i \cdot c_{n-i}$$
and in my case $c_1=\frac{1}{3}$, but my question is **not** limited to this initial condition.

My example: $c_1=\frac{1}{3}$, $c_2=\frac{1}{3^2 \cdot 5}$, $c_3=\frac{2}{3^3\cdot 5 \cdot 7}$, $c_4=\frac{27}{3^4\cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 9}=\frac{1}{3^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7}$, $c_5=\frac{90}{3^5\cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 9 \cdot 11}=\frac{10}{3^5\cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11}$ and so on.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It’s the Catalan numbers divided by something.  You’d probably have success finding a generating function for them.

Comment: The generating function seems to be $1 - \sqrt{x} \cot(\sqrt{x})$.  But your computations are a bit off: I get $c_4 = 1/4725$ and $c_5 =2/93555$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks! and yes, I miscomputed starting from $c_3$. I am correcting the computation.

Comment: What @RobertIsrael says is correct: If we set $f = \sum_{n\geq 1} c_n x^{2n}$, then the recursive equation translates into $f^2 = \left(xf\right)' - x^2$, and this ODE indeed has solution $f = 1 - x \cot x$. You can now [enter "1 - x cot x" in Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%221+-+x+cot+x%22&btnG=) and find some surprisingly relevant hits, eventually getting to [the Langevin function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_and_Langevin_functions#Langevin_function).

Comment: Why did you tag this question "dg.differential-geometry"? Did I miss something?

Comment: @SebastianGoette I did not mention it in my question but those numbers appeared while I was doing computation with dg manifolds. I was hoping maybe I could find any differential geometric situation where those sequence appear.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks a lot. Learnt a lot to deal with this kind of questions

Comment: As mentioned in comments, the sequence comes from the Taylor series of $\cot.$ They are implicit in [OEIS sequence A002431](https://oeis.org/A002431) "Numerators in Taylor series for cot x." Note that $c_n/(3c_1)^n$  does not depend on $c_1$ so without loss of generality $c_1=1/3$ is generic.